# AdMob covers my EditText and TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, admob

I have implemented AdMob adds in Java and don't know how to fix one thing. When my adds appears my view is in the same positon so adds are on top and cover few thing. Do You know how to repair this?

```
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(adView, params);


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();


    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="200"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    tools:context="com.converter_numeralsystem.app.MainActivity">
    <TextView
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/number"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvNumber" />

    <TextView
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber"
    android:text="@string/result"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvResult" />

    <EditText
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/etNumber"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/enter_numb"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvNumber"/>
    <EditText
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/etResult"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/et_result"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvResult"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_below="@id/etResult">

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:id="@+id/bCalculate"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bReset" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="63"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reset"
            android:id="@+id/bReset"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bCalculate" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearButtons"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/topLinear">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scroll">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/from"
                android:id="@+id/tvFrom"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvResult"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvFrom"
                android:id="@+id/rgFrom"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                <RadioButton

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r2From"
                    android:text="@string/dwa"/>


                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r8From"
                    android:text="@string/osiem"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="75dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r10From"
                    android:text="@string/dziesiec"
                    android:layout_below="@id/r2From"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2From" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r16From"
                    android:text="@string/szesnascie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/r8From"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8From"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/to"
                android:id="@+id/tvTo"
                android:layout_below="@id/rgFrom"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvTo"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/rgTO">

                <RadioButton
                    android:checked="true"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r2TO"
                    android:text="@string/dwa"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r8TO"
                    android:text="@string/osiem"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="75dp" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r10TO"

                    android:text="@string/dziesiec"
                    android:layout_below="@id/r2TO"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2TO" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/r16TO"

                    android:text="@string/szesnascie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/r8TO"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8TO"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP` rule to `params`...

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

So, your code will be...

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

layout.addView(adView, params);
```

**Update:**

Add a `LinearLayout` to your layout before `tvNumber` textView which will contain the `AdView` as below and add `android:layout_below="@+id/ad_layout"` as an attribute to the `tvNumber` textview...

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

So, your updated XML layout will be as follows...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="200"
    tools:context="com.converter_numeralsystem.app.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/number"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
        android:hint="@string/enter_numb"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvResult"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:hint="@string/et_result"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/etResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCalculate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bReset"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="@string/calculate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bReset"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bCalculate"
            android:layout_weight="63"
            android:text="@string/reset" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearButtons" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFrom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvResult"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/from"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rgFrom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvFrom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r2From"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/dwa" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r8From"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                        android:text="@string/osiem" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r10From"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2From"
                        android:layout_below="@id/r2From"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/dziesiec" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r16From"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8From"
                        android:layout_below="@id/r8From"
                        android:text="@string/szesnascie" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rgFrom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rgTO"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTo"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r2TO"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/dwa" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r8TO"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                        android:text="@string/osiem" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r10TO"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/r2TO"
                        android:layout_below="@id/r2TO"
                        android:text="@string/dziesiec" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r16TO"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/r8TO"
                        android:layout_below="@id/r8TO"
                        android:text="@string/szesnascie" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, change your code as below...

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layout.addView(adView, params);
```

**Another Update:**

Declare `layout` at class level and change `layout's` visibility as below...

```
if(checkInternetConnection()==true){

    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

} else {

    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Place this condition where you need to control the visibility of `layout`.

Comment: then used `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);`

Comment: @HamidShatu again +1 up for your _Awesome_ answer.

Comment: It's still incorrect. Add is on top and my view is covered by this add. I haven't got anything on the bottom, so I thought it was correct. Sorry for that.

Comment: @MaciejSocha...I have updated my answer...I think now you will get what you want.

Comment: It's working perfectly, but when I turn off internet connection there is blank space. It should disappear.

Comment: then the visibility to `GONE` and when internet connection will available then set visibility to `VISIBLE`.

Comment: I need to add this in Java or XML? In XML is only this: android:visibility="gone"

Comment: I have something like this and I don't know where I can set visibility.

 if(checkInternetConnection()==true){
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.addView(adView, params);
        }